# How to fix import:command not found in java

Tags: java, gradle, syntax, runtime-error, importerror

Every time I try to run my project I get these error messages and I cannot figure out what is wrong. I checked the encoding on all files and it is correct and have tried dos2unix. I have no idea what the problem could be.

```
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 1: package: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 3: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 4: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 5: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 6: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 7: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 8: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 10: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 11: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 12: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 13: import: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 16: /Applications: is a directory
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 17: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 18: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 19: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 20: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 21: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 22: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 23: README.md: command not found
src/main/java/prj02/HuffmanCoding.java: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Code the errors are referring to:

```
package prj02;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

The syntax errors refer to a Javadoc comment(line 24):

```
/**
 * The Huffman Encoding Algorithm
 *
 * This is a data compression algorithm designed by David A. Huffman and published in 1952
 *
 * What it does is it takes a string and by constructing a special binary tree with the frequencies of each character.
 * This tree generates special prefix codes that make the size of each string encoded a lot smaller, thus saving space.
 *(Implementation)
 * @version 2.0
 * @since 10/16/2021
 */
```

I am using gradle to build this project. The errors are from bash. And yes, I have compiled the project.

Comment: what are you running?  *The syntax errors refer to a Javadoc comment* - what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried ***compiling*** this source code?

Comment: I think could be something about your classpath. What do you use for building ( maven, Gradle ). Does your error come from ide or some command bash?

Comment: You are trying to execute a `.java` file directly, and the errors you see come from the shell. You need to compile your code with `javac` and run it with `java`. Please read a basic tutorial.

Comment: @DilermandoLima I used Gradle and the error is coming from ide(IntelliJ) terminal